# How to safely change the color of a fire tornado?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, home-experiment, safety, color, pyrotechnics

So I've been watching a lot of fire tornado videos and I came across one that had a reasonable and safe setup (around the 3:23 mark):

[Fire Tornado DIY](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1BxQd6AGYiI)

Is there a way to change the color of the fire tornado using the butane-powered base option?

The initial display of the tealight allows for either powdered/liquid chemicals to be added, but how would one safely add chemicals such as alcohol with the butane base setup?